# Finding the count of an variable using switch Statment

Tags: java, switch-statement, max, min

In this application I have to enter the total sales of every month from Jan 2010 to Dec 2014.(48 inputs)
I need to display the month of the year which has min sales and max sales.

The problem is I am not getting the desired output.

```
package xxxxxxx;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{

    public static void main ( String [] args ){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        int getInt=0;
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double average = 0;
        boolean number = true;
        int choice=0;

        while ( number == true )
        {
            System.out.println("Enter A Sales for a month  : ");
            getInt = keyboard.nextInt();
            choice++;
            if ( getInt < 0 )
                number = false;
            else
            {
                if ( getInt > max )
                    max = getInt;

                if ( getInt <= min )
                    min = getInt;

                sum += getInt;
                count++;
            }
        }  
        int maxy=choice%12;
        switch(maxy){
            case 1 :
                System.out.println("It's Month is : "+" Januray of 2010 !"+max);
                break;
            case 2 :
                System.out.println("It's Month is : "+" Februray of 2010 !"+max);
                break;
            case 3 :
                System.out.println("It's month is : "+" March of 2010 !"+max);
                break;
            case 4 :
                System.out.println("It's month is : "+" April of 2010 !"+max);
                break;
            case 5 :
                System.out.println("It's month is : "+" May of 2010 ! "+max);
                 .
                 .
                 .
        }
        average = ( sum ) / ( count );
        System.out.println( "Sum = " + sum );
        System.out.println( "Average = " + average );
        System.out.println( "Max = " + max );
        System.out.println( "Minimum = " + min );
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: Are you aware that the whole point of computers is not to do automatic tasks yourself?

Comment: Good for you.  Now, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the problem is it's not showing the name of the month ! ....

Comment: What in the world are you doing? This has to be the most convoluted thing I have seen

Comment: Your code contains this:  " maxy=choice/12 ".   Did you mean "maxy=choice%12"  ?

Comment: Well Brian , the problem is I'm not allowed to use arrays ! + any java methods (like Calendar.getInstance()..etc) , i have to show the  name of the Max value's month and year using switch Statement ...

Comment: oww Sorry Darius , yes it should be %12 , still ..it doesn't work.

Comment: If it's supposed to be % 12 please change your code to reflect that.

Comment: Currently, it takes the number of values you input, %12 and then interprets that number (+1) as month of the year. Is that what you want? **Also: If that is some sort of programming exercise, I kindly request to shoot the teacher/prof/whatever to the moon (on the dark side where the nazis have built their evil base!).**

Comment: well brimborium i would have shoot our prof to the moon , but he is just simply stupid ,i asked him this question which he asked me in the first place , he got confused !

Comment: @brimborium I agree this is not a job for switches. I would personally use an array I think. Though as I understand it since the switch cases are contiguous (1, 2, 3...etc) the byte code will be a branch table which is lightning fast. There is only a single evaluation and the control flow jumps immediately to the next instruction. Might be fast as a helper method.

Comment: @Radiodef The reason not to use this is not because of performance (sorry for the double negatives :D). It's because of readability, structure and maintenance. For things like these you should never choose performance over aesthetics unless you bump into problems after the first implementation (or see them coming ^^). At least imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're wanting is the following if you have to use a switch and don't want to use something like a Date formatting class:

```
int year = 2010 + choice / 12;
int month = 1 + choice % 12;

switch (month) {
    case 1: System.out.println("January " + year);
            break;
    case 2: System.out.println("February " + year);
            break;

    // so on
}
```

BTW I don't see anything in your code that restricts the # of inputs to 48 like you say is a spec. You can easily add this to your while loop:

```
while (number == true && count < 48) {

}
```

And further reduce it to:

```
while (number && count < 48) {

}
```

Because booleans are a boolean themselves you do not need to check `if (value == true)` and `if (value == false)`, rather you should check `if (value)` and `if (!value)`.

However your `number` variable is actually redundant and can be removed entirely if you use a break. I also think you mean to exit before incrementing `choice` IE looks like the user enters a negative number to end early. If you increment the control this will screw up your average. It looks like you created your second variable `count` for this purpose but I don't think you need it. You just need to refactor.

I also recommend checking `count` before doing your average. In your code right now the user can abort the loop immediately and you'll get a divide by zero.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a sales for the month: ");
    getInt = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (getInt < 0) break;

    if (getInt > max) max = getInt;
    if (getInt < min) min = getInt;

    sum += getInt;
    count++;

} while (count < 48);

if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("No sales ever!");
    return;
}

int year = 2010 + count / 12;
int month = 1 + count % 12;
```

Comment: thank god you understood the problem ... the thing is even with your solution the program declares the second input to May , what do you think might cause this problem ?

Comment: See my update which has some general comments on your loop. I think you are incrementing your control variable an extra time. I refactored your loop so it is much smaller and compact (and I think does what you intended it to do).

Comment: You're welcome. If it's the solution make sure to mark it as such so the question is solved. : )

Answer (score 0):

To get the current month just use this

```
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

and the year is

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

putting it all together

```
private static String getMonthName(int month) {
  switch (month - 1) {
  case Calendar.JANUARY: return "January";
  case Calendar.FEBRUARY: return "February";
  case Calendar.MARCH: return "March";
  case Calendar.APRIL: return "April";
  case Calendar.MAY: return "May";
  case Calendar.JUNE: return "June";
  case Calendar.JULY: return "July";
  case Calendar.AUGUST: return "August";
  case Calendar.SEPTEMBER: return "September";
  case Calendar.OCTOBER: return "October";
  case Calendar.NOVEMBER: return "November";
  case Calendar.DECEMBER: return "December";
  default:
    System.err.println("month " + month
        + " unknown, use January.");
    return "January";
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -48);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println(getMonthName(month) + " " + year);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you got what he is asking?